# How to interpolate this list of data

Tags: interpolation

Can anyone help me to interpolate this list of data?

I try to use Interpolation function but think the number of points it's not enough.

Here I show the result using ListPlot:

[image]

I want to interpolate beacuse I want the "y" for a specific value of "x".

[List of data](https://pastebin.com/cD7ACXNZ)

Comment: Which `y` do you want for `x==.04`?

Comment: Do you want a parametric interpolation (of the form $(x(s),y(s)$)?

Comment: Let supose the horizontal axes is "x" and the vertical is "y". I want a interpolation which gives me y(x).

Comment: Carl's question focuses on the fact that there is not a unique value for `y[0.04]`.  In US lingo, we say the graph fails the Vertical Line Test and does not define y as a function of x.

Comment: Actually, I have my "y" and I want my "x" for this specific "y".

Comment: Your last comment contradicts the second-to-the-last sentence of your question. Very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/cD7ACXNZ.txt", "Table"];
```

As stated in the comments, your `y` is not a function of `x` since it is not single-valued. To form a single-valued function reverse the data point values, i.e., look at `{y, x}` rather than `{x, y}`.

```
data2 = Reverse /@ data;

f = Interpolation[data2];

{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[data2[[All, 1]]];

Plot[f[y], {y, ymin, ymax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rob Hanlon. Problem solved.